# Are WiFi adapters secure?

Tags: wireless-networking, security

I know old and outdated routers are security risks, but what about old WiFi adapaters? Can using an old WiFi adapter pose a security risk?

Comment: Sounds more suited to https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It depends what you're trying to protect against... using RF instead of a Wire is going to be a security risk at the most fundamental level...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the older adapter only supports WEP or WPA-1.

Some older adapters/cards were updated with new drivers to support newer encryption methods. The only way to tell is to update to the manufacturers latest, or in your case probably the last updated drivers for the adapter. (They may also list it with the model info on the manufacturers website with what it actually supports)

WPA2-PSK is still considered secure as long as you use 16 Digit alpha-numerical passwords with uppercase lowercase & special characters. (With **no WPS activated**)

**WPA** don't use it, it's considered insecure because it doesn't include the SSID in the encryption hash. This means rainbow-tables can easily be used against it greatly reducing cracking times on handshakes.

**WEP** is broken, **don't use it**. There is nothing that you would be able to do to stop someone from breaking into this encryption.

**WPS** is also considered broken, it is not recommended to have this service turned on in the router.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the secirity standards supported. You can chose WEP, WPA, WPA2, PSK or enterprise, RADIUS.
The old hardware maybe is less secure because it can be outdated and not supporting that standars of security or not having recent firmware upgrades, but the main security resides on secutity protocol or autentication choosen.